# Link CSS into SKIN file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, skin

I have a skin file inside the App_Themes and also a css file . I have used a Gridview styling css and import that in the skin file.

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="GridViewStyle" runat="server" >
    <FooterStyle CssClass="GridViewFooterStyle" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />    
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridViewSelectedRowStyle" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridViewPagerStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

But how can I link the css file into this skin file . I am not getting the design at runtime .

And My Web.Config file as

```
<pages themes="summer">
```

Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Page directive to use Themes file in individual page.

```
<%@ Page Theme="ThemeName" %>
<%@ Page StyleSheetTheme="ThemeName" %>
```

For more deatil. [Check it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yy5hxdk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In Web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages StyleSheetTheme="Themename" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```